# No named cycles in template. 'row1,row2' is not defined

Tags: django, templates

In my django inline formset, form html:

```
{% block body %}        
    <h2>Profile</h2>
    <hr>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}

            <table class="table">
                {{ familymembers.management_form }}

                {% for form in familymembers.forms %}
                    {% if forloop.first %}
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                                <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                    {% endif %}
                    <tr class="{% cycle row1,row2 %} formset_row">
                        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                            <td>
                                {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
                                {% if forloop.first %}
                                    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                                        {{ hidden }}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                {% endif %}
                                {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                                {{ field }}
                            </td>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Save"/> <a href="{% url 'profile-list' %}">back to the list</a>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

When I tried to open form it gives

TemplateSyntaxError at /profile/add/
No named cycles in template. 'row1,row2' is not defined

How could I avoid this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not how you use that tag, as [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle) show. The values should be separated by spaces, not commas, and if they are literal strings they should be in quotes.

```
{% cycle "row1" "row2" %}
```

Comment: FWIW. That is how you used that tag in earlier versions. So this was likely an issue with upgrading to a newer version of Django.

Answer (score 1):

If you still get an error, you can try:

```
class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %} formset_row"
```